# How to split string with whitespaces and character between it

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string that looks like following example:

```
US Latina Calcio v AS Varese 1910
```

I would like to split this string into two strings using regular expression. 
I want to make separator: `"whitespace"+"v"+"whitespace"`.

I tried like that, but it doesn't work:

```
buffer = match.split("\\sv\\s");
```

Comment: What result do you get after the split? It [works fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/NR1hdd).

Comment: works fine, what is not working for you?

Comment: Could you add more info about why do you think it is not working? Do you get some error or output is not what you expect it to be?

Comment: Okey, sorry, you were right, it works. I made very stupid mistake - didn't initialize two strings variables that were getting the value after split and thus it didn't work. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Piotr Sagalara Add the solution as answer in order to be helpfull for future similar problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I didn't initialize two strings variables that were getting the values after split and thus it didn't work. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pattern and Matcher Classes. They provide more convenience when it comes to regex. use the expression as \sv\s. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would someone want to write this regex as `[\s]v[\s]` instead of `\sv\s`? Also `split` uses Pattern and Matcher classes internally so it is simplest way to do what OP wants IMO.